# How to add tags in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am creating few resources via terraform in aws. I want to define some tags and add it to each resource. can we define it in one file and apply it to all. few examples , i saw , looks like we can define tags in one file and it applies to all of the resources in cloudforamtion , not sure how to do it terraform.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}


resource "aws_instance" "someinstance" {
  ami           = "ami-1"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

module "load_balancers" "someloadbalancer"{
  ...
}
module "autoscaling_groups" "autoscalinggroup"{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you've done much research?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/default_tags
or you can define your common tags with a locals https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals for a start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up default tags as a variabile in `variables.tf`, e.g.

```
variable "tags" {
   default = {
     Environment = "production"
   }
}
```

then, pass into your modules in your root module:

```
module "load_balancers" "someloadbalancer"{
  ...
  tags = var.tags
}
module "autoscaling_groups" "autoscalinggroup"{
  ...
  tags = var.tags
}
```

In each module you would define variable tags, and use it in the actual resources, e.g.:

```
variable "tags" {}

resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  ...
  tags = var.tags
}
```